# Airbnb-like sites for long term stay

Tags: rental, long-term, serbia, montenegro

I want to explore the whole sharing economy and I was wondering if there are sites similar to Airbnb, but primary for long time stay. I wanted to move somewhere in Taiwan, Thailand, Montenegro and Serbia for 1 or 2 months while having both pleasure time and working remotely. Airbnb due to it's focus on short time stay can be pricey.

I know that there are good long term offers on Airbnb, and I can negotiate directly, but still, I'm interested in other online resources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is anything specific for this length of stay other than figuring out where the most local classified ads are (Kijiji, Craigslist, something local) and trying to arrange something directly.

As far as Airbnb goes, they have a specific site [airbnb.com/sublets](https://www.airbnb.com/sublets) for this term of stay, advantage of using this over regular search tool is that it automatically searches for the same periods of time as discount pricing is set up for (2 weeks, a month, etc.). If you fall a few days short of these limits (you need three weeks, but discount pricing is one month) pricing is sometimes actually higher total if they use the expensive per-night price for three weeks (21 days * daily rate) instead of finding the cheaper price for an entire month (monthly rate).

[Zilyo](https://zilyo.com/) is a nice tool that shows composite results for Airbnb plus 20 odd similar sites as well, in some areas this actually lends a ton more results than airbnb alone.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to pay a minimum of $10 per day for accommodation using any booking sites like AirBnB.

One option would be to look on the site: https://www.workaway.info/

And see if you can come up with some sort of deal.

---

The only way you will find somewhere really cheap is by first going somewhere and then trying to find a place to stay with a local. I wouldn't have thought this would be too hard and you will probably be able to find some places for next to nothing. I stayed in Zajecar, Serbia for 80 days, in a house arranged by a Serbian friend, that was usually rented out to students, but was vacant in the summer. It was £50 / month, including electric, which is about 70 EUR/USD. I had serious internet problems though, which was an issue, as like you I work remotely. However, you can get cheap 3G. Given that unemployment is about 17-18% and the the minimum wage, after tax, is about $1/hour, I wouldn't have thought it would be too difficult to find a place if you want to offer something like $100, or maybe even $50, for something in an apartment.

The best places to try and look for a place like this would be places that are not popular with tourists, as I found that they are very curious when an outsider comes. I would recommend Pirot, in the south-east, when I was there, I was asked lots of questions (in Serbian and English) in almost every shop I went to and even in the street. One even offered me a place to stay.

If you really want to chance it, go to a small village and offer something like $50-100 / month to people there. I'm pretty sure you will find somewhere, as many people in the villages live off a very small income from selling vegetables in the summer-autumn.

This all, of course, becomes difficult if you cannot speak Serbian.

Comment: What's the linked website about? Are you affiliated with it? (Sorry, typo.)

Comment: If I was the sort of person who went about spamming my link, or getting other people to do it for me, I don't think I'd be disclosing that fact when questioned. You can however check my profiles. I have a decent rep. on StackExchance, which I think should be enough to exempt me from suspicion of spamming.

WorkAway is a site where you can fin people to host you for free in exchange for work.

Comment: [Not disclosing that fact is exactly what causes SE to consider the post spam](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3148/advertising-thats-not-spam/3149#3149), [regardless of reputation and posting history](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/3472/22140). Please don't be offended by my question. Being a new user on Travel SE I felt compelled to ask. If you are not affiliated, just state this in the post and we can stop worrying about this without getting any more feelings hurt. ;) Please add details of WorkAway to your answer since it's valuable content.